# python selecting an individual data frame data from a combined data frame using index

Tags: python, dataframe

I have three dataframes of different length. I am combining them into one dataframe for saving it. Now, I want to retrieve individual dataframe data from the combined dataframe using index. A sample of my problem is given below:

```
df1 = 
   data
0   10
1   20

df2 = 
   data
0   100
1   200
2   300

df3 = 
   data
0   1000
1   2000
2   3000
3   4000

combdf = pd.concat ([df1,df2,df3],ignore_index=True])

combdf = 
    data
0   10
1   20
2   100
3   200
4   300
5   1000
6   2000
7   3000
8   4000
```

I want to retrieve data of individual data frames from combdf. My code:

```
data_len = [len(df1),len(df2),len(df3)]
for k in range(0,len(data_len),1):
    if k==0:
        st_id = 0
    else:
        st_id = sum(data_len[:k])
    ed_id = st_id+data_len[k]
    print(combdf.iloc[st_id:ed_id])
```

Above code is working fine. Is there a better approach than this which does not use for loop?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calculating the indices while looping you can generate them first then use those to loop.

```
data_len = [0, len(df1),len(df2),len(df3)]
data_index = np.cumsum(data_len) #contains [0,2,5,11]
for i in range(len(data_index)-1):
    print(df.iloc[data_index[i]:data_index[i+1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a second index column with `pd.MultiIndex` that has the name of the original DataFrame. Below you can see a sample of how you could do this:

```py
import pandas as pd 

df_dict = {}

df_dict['df1'] = pd.DataFrame([10, 20])
df_dict['df2'] = pd.DataFrame([100, 200, 300])
df_dict['df3'] = pd.DataFrame([1000, 2000, 3000, 4000])

for df_name, df in df_dict.items():

    # Generate second level of index
    df_index_to_array = df.index.tolist()
    df_index_second_level = [df_name for i in range(0, df.shape[0])]

    df_idx_multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([
        df_index_to_array,
        df_index_second_level
    ])

    df_dict[df_name] = df.set_index(df_idx_multi_index)

df_list = [df for _, df in df_dict.items()]

comb_df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

This would result in:

```
          0
0 df1    10
1 df1    20
0 df2   100
1 df2   200
2 df2   300
0 df3  1000
1 df3  2000
2 df3  3000
3 df3  4000
```

In order to access each item, you could you use `.loc` from `pandas`, for example:

```py
>>> comb_df.loc[0, 'df2']
0 100
Name: (0, df2), dtype: int64
```